# Get checkbox value as zero if not selected

Tags: php, jquery

I have 3 checkboxes, and I store values of these checkboxes to database.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="estate-checkbox[]"></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="estate-checkbox[]"></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="estate-checkbox[]"></li>
</ul>
```

**Server side:**

```
if(isset($_POST['estate-checkbox'])){
    $safeestatecheckbox = implode(",",$_POST["estate-checkbox"]);
} else {
    $safeestatecheckbox = '';
}
```

If user check all checkboxes, it will store in db like this:

```
1, 2, 3
```

If select one, or just two, it store like this:

```
1, 3
```

I want if user not select a checkbox, it store to database as zero, like this

```
1, 0, 3
```

**So the question is,** how can I get checkbox value as 0, if it not selected in `$_POST['estate-checkbox']` ?

Comment: Why not check on the server side if a value is not given, and use a 0 in that case?  You need to be validating the input on the server anyway.

Comment: @Taplar on other page, I get it from database as array with 3 items, I show icon based on those values. so I need to have always 3 values on database, in other hand, 3 items in array

Comment: And you still have to validate your input on the server when a user submits.  Nothing will stop a user from right clicking on your page, inspecting and element, and changing one of the values to like 504 or whatever they want.

Comment: There's no way to get that automatically, you'll need to do it in your PHP code.

Comment: Why do you need the `0`? Can't you just detect that `2` isn't in the array?

Comment: @Barmar  I get data from db and show on a page with `$option = explode(',', $ed["estate_option"]);` and show if checked or not like this: `<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="estate-checkbox[]" <?=$option[0] == 1 ? 'checked' : '' ?>>` and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only checked boxes get sent to the server, there's no way to make it send another value for the unchecked boxes.

You can fill in the missing values in PHP:

```
$estates = [];
$estate_checkboxes = array_flip($_POST['estate-checkbox']);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $max_estates; $i++) {
    if (isset($estate_checkboxes[$i])) {
        $estates[] = $i;
    } else {
        $estates[] = 0;
    }
}

$safeestatecheckbox = implode(', ', $estates);
```

Comment: And `$max_estates` ? 3?

Comment: Set that to the maximum number of checkboxes. If the checkboxes are created dynamically on the client, it will need to send the count as a hidden input.

Comment: Two things, one unclosed bracket. but It store empty (nothing) in database, any idea?

Comment: Not sure why. BTW, storing comma-separated lists in databases is poor design, you should normalize your tables.

Comment: Okay, let me check on my own. I have no idea what do you mean of *normalize your tables* , if I want to store checkboxes values, how can I do this except comma separated ?

Comment: My code works here: https://ideone.com/S9Kpds

Comment: Use a table with a separate row for each value, with a foreign key referencing the row in the main table.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to have a `hidden` field that updates every click of checkboxes

```js
$('[name="estate-checkbox[]"]').click(function() {
  var arr = [];
  $('[name="estate-checkbox[]"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) arr.push($(this).val());
    else arr.push(0);
  })

  $('[name="estate-checkbox-values"]').val(arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="estate-checkbox[]"></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="estate-checkbox[]"></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="estate-checkbox[]"></li>
</ul>

<!----- Change into type hidden ----->
<input type="text" name="estate-checkbox-values">
```

On your PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['estate-checkbox-values'])){
    $safeestatecheckbox = $_POST['estate-checkbox-values'];
} else {
    $safeestatecheckbox = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['estate-checkbox'])){
    $temp = [1, 2, 3];
    foreach($temp as $key => $val){
        if(array_search($val, $_POST['estate-checkbox']) === false){
            $temp[$key] = 0;
        }
    }
    $safeestatecheckbox = implode(',', $temp);
} else {
    $safeestatecheckbox = '';
}
```